# How can I re-render the ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript

I just want to know how can I rerender the ngFor or refresh a component (hello.component.ts). Instead of text could be images or charts.

Here is an simple example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mmrem2)

Solution:

```
 public show = true;
 addData(data){
      this.data.push(data);
      this.reload();
    }
  reload() {
    this.show = false;
    setTimeout(() => this.show = true);
  }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not sure if I understood your needs, but you may try simple ngIf and zero-timeout approach to re-render the component's template:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<div *ngIf="show">
... your template
</div>`
})
export class HelloComponent  {

  public show = true;

  // ... your code

  reload() {
    this.show = false;
    setTimeout(() => this.show = true);
  }

}
```

Call the `reload` method when you need to "reload" your component. By setting `show` value to false and waiting for 1 event loop is done (`setTimeout`), you destroy inner template. By setting `show` value to true after this, you render inner template again.

---

**UPD**. Also you may force the Angular to re-render data-specific parts of your component's template by changing that data manually:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `...
<div *ngFor="let i of data">
  {{i}}...
</div>`
})
export class HelloComponent  {

  public data = [];

  // ... your code

  reloadData() {
    this.data = [...this.data];
  }

}
```

This would allow you to "reload" the data array only, so `NgFor` will handle it's inner template re-rendering automatically. By assigning new value to `this.data` (spread operator), you say to Angular that the parts of the template that are bound with `data` should be re-built.

Comment: Hi, Just wanted to know, is this a good practice to reload the component .?

Comment: Why don’t you just repopulate the `ngFor` array? Angular will re-render automatically.

Comment: @Kokodoko I've added the option you mentioned, thanks! Of course it seems more applicable in real life.

Comment: @FranklinPious There may be situations when you need to prevent component's template rendering. In that cases a global NgIf could be helpful. But for reloading, I think, it would be better to use something more specific. I updated the answer with data-reloading option.

Comment: Nice, thank you very much. I spend so much time with it. I setted the setTimeout in the wrong position. Above it was just an example and I will need it to update multiple charts. You saved my time

Comment: @Arash setTimeout is just to split two-pass setting show value between two phases of Angular Change detection. Without it the value will be re-assigned within a single synchronous callstack, so the Angular will not detect that show is changed.

Comment: @NoahTony Nice to hear it! (You should embed the code in your questions to avoid downvotes)

Comment: I added to my application but it is not working 100%, I created a new post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50677493/set-min-max-values-of-multiple-charts

Comment: I ended up needing to use the timeout. `data = [...data]` wasn't working, so I did `var save=data; data = []; timeout(() => data = save;)`

Comment: This is the simplest answer and the easiest to implement. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

**The challenge is to get angular to see your change and redraw.**

I recently worked through this with a coworker and found more than one way to do this.
Our issue had to do with filtering

In the StackBlitz you share, you use more than one technique.
I isolated just one portion, mutating the array that ngFor uses to draw the DOM elements.

[ngFor draw update mutate](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngfor-draw-update-mutate)

I'm also including the issue my coworker and I had. We wanted to have our list of items filtered using the value of an input box. Angular refused to redraw. Our solution was to add an ngModel to the input.

[ngFor draw update ngmodel](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngfor-draw-update-ngmodel)